# EE member management with multiple groups

Tags: safecracker, members, zoo-visitor

What are the recommended modules for managing members in channel entries that can have different member groups and member fields?

- Zoo Visitor seems to only have one group available - no use.
- Freemember seems to hook into the built in member fields, I would
  prefer to use channel entries.
- User from Solspace seems to be my only
  option?

Comment: With Zoo Visitor, it wouldn't work for you to just customize the Publish page view for each group to only show the fields that are relevant to them? You can assign members to individual member groups as well. Unless your needs are different than this?

Comment: I know what you're saying. I want to separate the groups completely - different channels if possible. Say for example you have a site which can register two groups - 'doctors' and 'patients', the field information is very different for the two groups so keeping separate channels and groups makes sense. I could do it the way you suggested but I think it's better to separate them. Can User do this?

Comment: Don't think User does that either (but I'm not 100%)...it would be hard to have multiple channels for member management for each group. We had a similar requirement and had to make due with only showing the necessary fields based on the group the person was assigned to. Sorry can't be of more help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Profile:Edit module, which is similar to Zoo Visitor, but I personally prefer it more.

Comment: You prefer which one more?

Comment: I prefer Profile:edit